# plot a scatter graph for a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Please I need help I want to plot a graph using

```
pandas.dataframe.plot(kind='scatter' , x=x , y=y )
```

for a dictionary type {'2022-01-30': 50, '2022-01-31': 152, '2022-02-01': 41 }

Please how can I use dictionary since i need a title

It is giving me the `error x is not defined`
`x is the key` and
`y is the value`

but on the graph x should be  'Date' and y should be 'Quantity'

Comment: Could you please share the code that you've tried?

Comment: @dm2: `pandas.dataframe.plot(kind='scatter' , x=x , y=y )` is the code he tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a DataFrame first:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'2022-01-30': 50, '2022-01-31': 152, '2022-02-01': 41}
df = pd.Series(data, name='y').rename_axis('x').reset_index()
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't plot a dict type with a dataframe function. Thus two possibilities :

- use your dictionnary and follow [Plot a scatter plot in python with matplotlib with dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822592/plot-a-scatter-plot-in-python-with-matplotlib-with-dictionary) (use of `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`)
- convert your dictionnary to dataframe with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` and then use `pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter(x=x, y=y)`

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the keys & values

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'2022-01-30': 50, '2022-01-31': 152, '2022-02-01': 41}
x, y = data.keys(), data.values()

plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Comment: This is a repetition of the previous comment,that anticipate this answer.